# How to debug binary c/c++ program with gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I currently have a binary program that usually ends freezing up after some time using.

For instance I am executing such a program with the following command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/arquivos/Gtk+-3.4.0/lib/:/xorg/X11-1.4.4/lib/:/xorg/Xcb-1.4/lib/:/arquivos/Dbus-1.10.2/lib gdb ./firefox
```

P.S:I load against these libraries because my system lacks some of them or some symbol inside them.

Then already inside gdb, I type "run" and Firefox loads. After some time of use, it might freeze entirely (it usually does), with the background becoming of solid color. Normally it happens a few moments after I use the mouse to grab the roll up/down bar on the right side and swiftly move it up and down.

Gdb does not tell me anything when the freeze happens

This same firefox binnary works fine on other Linux, so I believe the problem is cause by the interaction of it with some of the libraries loaded by LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I did tested with different versions of X11 and Xcb (although both were built using the same Xorgproto, Xau and pthread stub). But nothing changed.

So I am a bit lost about to figure out which library is the culprit and open to suggestions.

Edited: output of "thread apply all where"

```
Thread 79 (Thread 0x7fffd46ff700 (LWP 7633)):
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
#1  0x00007ffff8055746 in mozilla::detail::ConditionVariableImpl::wait(mozilla::detail::MutexImpl&) ()
#2  0x00007fffed64dc81 in ?? () from /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/firefox-78.15.0-esr/libxul.so
#6  0x00007ffff7fb8654 in ?? () from /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/firefox-78.15.0-esr/libnspr4.so
#7  0x00007ffff7bb7054 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffd46ff700) at pthread_create.c:309
#8  0x00007ffff6eb5d3d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111



Thread 76 (Thread 0x7fffd46be700 (LWP 7626)):
#0  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:238
#1  0x00007ffff80558be in mozilla::detail::ConditionVariableImpl::wait_for(mozilla::detail::MutexImpl&, mozilla::BaseTimeDuration<mozilla::TimeDurationValueCalculator> const&) ()
```

ox-78.15.0-esr/libxul.so

Comment: "Gdb does not tell me anything when the freeze happens" It doesn't know. The program under debug might enter an infinite loop or a deadlock state. The debugger does not detect those automatically. You need to interrupt the execution (normally by pressing Ctrl-C) and debug as usual: examine variables, set breakpoints, single-step, whatever.

Comment: When I press ctrl+c I receive:    Thread 1 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
185 ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S: No such file or directory.

Comment: That's more or less expected. Now you figure out what to do next. And then what to do after that.

Answer (score 0):

> Gdb does not tell me anything when the freeze happens

Unfortunately, you will likely *not* be able to debug this, because doing so requires understanding of how `X11` event dispatch works. It is likely that `firefox` is blocked waiting for some `XEvent` to be delivered, and that even never comes.

That said, you *can* get some additional info about where the binary is stuck, by using Control-C to regain `(gdb)` prompt, and using `thread apply all where` command.

That will tell you where all the threads are. Once you have that, you'll discover that each thread is waiting for something. Figuring out which thread is waiting for what will eventually lead to understanding the problem, but that figuring out requires knowing internals of both the `firefox` itself, and the `X11` libraries, which you appear to not yet have.

---

n.m. commented: "... debug as usual: examine variables, set breakpoints, single-step, whatever."

Unfortunately that approach will not work here: once `firefox` is in a bad state, you can't *continue* -- you need to go "back in time".

But using [reversible debugger](https://rr-project.org/), you *can* do exactly that. Learning how to use `rr` will serve you well even if you don't manage to debug this particular problem.